# Implementation Secure messaging in EHR through Direct protocol

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, messaging, sta

I'm working on EHR secure messaging in ASP.NET. I have already configured the direct project on virtual machine. Now I have no clue where to start, I want to integrate my EHR application with STA/HISP in order to achieve secure messaging. Is there any service which I need to publish, to integrate STA/HISP with my EHR application.

Any answer will be very helpful to me.

I'm following the link below.
http://bluebuttonplus.org/transmit-using-direct.html

Answer (score 3):

As stated [here](http://bluebuttonplus.org/privacy.html) the implementation of a secure mechanism should be HIPAA compliant. Usually, these standards or guidelines produced by standardization organizations (HIPAA, HL7, ISO, CEN, Continua alliance etc), rely heavily on standard technical solutions (eg https, PKI etc). The problem is that you have to identify and interpret the obligations coming out of the selected standard. This is something that **you have to do it by yourself** for two reasons. First, you are the one knowing your project requirements and needs for standardization. Sharing these details on a forum is neither practical or wise. Second, **it is a non-trivial and a very time consuming task**.

If you have any technical question, for example how would I implement PKI, VPN, or HTTPS, then you would easily get a valid answer.

Hope I helped!

Comment: Sorry to hijack this, but what would be a good resource for asking questions related to HISP and Direct?